# How to use azure devops pipeline terraform to build oracle Cloud infra resources

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I want to use a pipeline with azure devops terraform to deploy resources in the oracle Cloud infra.
But i don't knew if the provider oci is supported or not.
I want to store the state file of oracle CI resources in the storage account azure.

Some one have a solution please ?

[image]

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code, post the *actual code*. Visually impaired people cannot read screenshots.

Comment: hi hamma what's the latest update for your issue? has the post of bursson helped?

Answer (score 0):

The [task you are using](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-terraform) does not support Oracle cloud, it only supports AWS, Azure and GCP.

If you want to target Oracle cloud, I suggest using [a generic bash task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/bash-v3?view=azure-pipelines) and using Terraform from CLI.

With Azure, the plan phase could look like this. With Oracle Cloud, you would have to replace the environment variables with [these.](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/API/SDKDocs/terraformproviderconfiguration.htm)

```
- task: Bash@3
  name: tf_plan
  displayName: 'Terraform plan'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      terraform init -backend-config=config/backend/${{ parameters.environment }}.json
      terraform plan -detailed-exitcode -out=tfplan -input=false
      exitcode=$?
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=terraform_exitcode;isOutput=true]$exitcode"
      if [ "$exitcode" -eq 1 ]; then
        exit $exitcode
      else 
        exit 0
      fi
    workingDirectory: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/Terraform/'
  env:
      ARM_CLIENT_ID: $(ArmClientId)
      ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: $(ArmClientSecret)
      ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: $(ArmSubscriptionId)
      ARM_TENANT_ID: $(ArmTenantId)
      TF_IN_AUTOMATION: true
```

Documentation on the parameters used can be found [here](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/plan)